# What database can perform full-text search within nested "directories" like file systems do?

Tags: database, hierarchical-data

```
root: {
  dir: {
    subDir: {
      subSubDir: {
        ...
      },
      ...
    },
    subDir_2: {
      ...
    }
  },
  dir_2: {
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I need to perform search within `dir` and all it's descendants, or in `subDir` and all it's descendants etc... i'll be slightly changing data quite frequently (10-100 times a day) including nodes renaming (`dir` to `directory` or whatever). Amount of data might be from 1MB till hundreds of MB and may be even about 1GB, quantity of nodes could be infinite, but average is up to 10k i guess. Depth of nesting will be, probably, up to 20.

The architecture might be changed, but the idea of "directories-like" representation must be there.

I thought about this alternative:

```
{
    [guid]: {title, text, path etc},
    [guid]: {title, text, path etc},
    [guid]: {title, text, path etc},
    [guid]: {title, text, path etc},
    [guid]: {title, text, path etc},
  }
```

This can be implemented in SQL database as well, but in case of a node rename i'll have to change `path` property in each node (raw) which might be extremely expensive.

Comment: I believe postgres has native JSON and fulltext searching

Comment: yes, also ES has it, mongodb has it, etc... However, I still don't see how to implement full-text search with the given conditions which are described above.

Comment: If you store that as a normalized, hierarchical data it's quite easy to do with a recursive SQL query in a relational database.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you! could you give more details or url? I don't quite understand what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with hierarchical data is easy in SQL when using a [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) and recursive common table expression.

Given e.g. the following setup:

create table directory 
(
   id integer primary key, 
   name varchar(100) not null,
   description text,
   parent_directory_id integer references directory
);

```
insert into directory (id, name, description, parent_directory_id)
values 
(1, 'Root', 'The root of all evil', null), 
(2, 'Toplevel1', 'First directory', 1),
(3, 'Toplevel2', 'Second directory', 1),
(4, 'T1-Subdir1', 'T1 - Some data', 2),
(5, 'T2-Subdir1', 'T2 - Irrelevant', 3),
(6, 'T1-S1-S1', 'T1-S1 important docs', 4),
(7, 'T1-S1-S2', 'T1-S1 trashcan', 4),
(8, 'T1-S1-S3', 'T1-S1 important scans', 4);
```

You could search for all sub-directories of "Toplevel1" that contain the string "important" using this query:

```
with recursive tree as (
  select id, name, description, parent_directory_id
  from directory
  where id = 2 -- The starting directory
  union all
  select cd.id, cd.name, cd.description, cd.parent_directory_id
  from directory cd
    join tree parent on cd.parent_directory_id = parent.id
)
select id,name,description
from tree
where description like '%important%';
```

The above returns:

```
id | name     | description          
---+----------+----------------------
 6 | T1-S1-S1 | T1-S1 important docs 
 8 | T1-S1-S3 | T1-S1 important scans
```

The `where` condition could also make use of the full text search capabilities of the database.